# Rearrange as per Master Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to display the raw data as per the headings of the Master sheet and show the relevant data in the columns.

I have "Raw Data" in Sheet1, Master Data Headings in Sheet 2 and I want the desire result in Sheet3.

Please Refer Below Screenshots:
Sheet 1- "Raw Data"

[image]

Sheet 2 - "Master Data Headings"

[image]

Sheet 3 - "Desired Results"

[image]

I tried the below formula but either it shows value as 0 or the headings are not as per the desired result ( sometimes blank as well ).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$H$4, MATCH($A$1, Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4, 0), MATCH(A$1, Sheet2!$I$1:$O$1, 0)), "")
```

Thank you Everyone in advance.

Comment: Hi Mayukh, Thank you for your response. this is a different scenario here. There are various headings added in the raw data now which are not required but still there. I tried sorting this from my end but no luck.

Comment: I checked again. As per the above screenshots, In raw data sheet there are many columns ( headings and the relevant data in the rows ) which are not required but the formulas I know only sort them and not eliminate the headings which are not required.

Comment: Yes, Mayukh. I tried from my end many times before posting this question on the community. I apologize.

Comment: Alright just posted, I have assumed you are using `MS365`

Comment: Thank you Mayukh, I'm using MS2021. Also, I would like to know from you regarding this formula. I want to learn from my end for it's application so that I can use it in future without asking again.

Comment: Put this in Sheet3, A1: `="" & OFFSET($Sheet1.$A$1, ROW($Sheet3.A1) - 1, MATCH($Sheet2.A$1, $Sheet1.$A$1:$H$1, 0) - 1)` and then copy it along and down as necessary. Note that if you need the rows to be in a different order to the raw data, you will need to do something with the `ROW($Sheet3.A1) - 1` part to change which row it fetches from.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your response. I'm getting an error.

Comment: Also one should note that using any `Volatile` function will lead to recalculate anytime anything on any open excel workbook changes, hence should be avoided as far as possible, also in this forums we hardly suggest about using volatile functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then following formula should work:*

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!A1:H4,XMATCH(Sheet2!A1:G1,Sheet1!A1:H1)), IF(x=0,"",x))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(x, INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$H$4,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Sheet1!$A$1:$H$4)),MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$G$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$H$1,0)), IF(x=0,"",x))
```

---